# Autofac asp.net MVC controller and viewmodel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, autofac

I'm getting this error:
[MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object. Object type 'MyProject.TestViewModel'.]

Global.asax.cs

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterControllers(typeof(MvcApplication).Assembly);
builder.RegisterType<MyProfileStore>().As<IMyProfileStore>();
builder.RegisterType<BreadCrumbImageService>().As<IBreadCrumbImageService>().SingleInstance();
builder.RegisterType<MyProfileViewModel>().As<IMyProfileViewModel>();
builder.RegisterType<BaseViewModel>().As<IBaseViewModel>();
builder.RegisterType<TestViewModel>().As<ITestViewModel>();
builder.RegisterType<TestSvc1>().As<ITestSvc>();
builder.RegisterType<TestSvc3>().As<ITestSvc>();
builder.RegisterType<TestSvc2>().As<ITestSvc>();
var container = builder.Build();
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
```

Controller

```
public class MyAccountController : BaseController
{
    public ActionResult Test(TestViewModel testViewModel)
    {
        _testViewModel = testViewModel;
        return View(_testViewModel);
    }
```

ViewModel

```
public class TestViewModel : ITestViewModel 
{
    private TestSvc1 _testSvc1;
    public string ViewModelText { get; set; }

    public TestViewModel(TestSvc1 testSvc1)
    {
        _testSvc1 = testSvc1;
        ViewModelText = _testSvc1.GetText();
    }
}
```

Are there additional steps I need to take with this? I was expecting that once I had registered the builder.RegisterType().As(); I would be good to go. I have tried to do the injection at the controller level in that constructor, and it gives me

```
None of the constructors found with 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type 'MyProject.MyAccountController' can be invoked with the available services and parameters:
Cannot resolve parameter 'MyProject.TestViewModel testViewModel' of constructor 'Void .ctor(MyProject.TestViewModel)'.
```

I'd like to stick with constructor injection, I don't know what I'm missing here.

Comment: This question was answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40362993/8116

Answer (score 0):

You have a dependency on `TestSvc1`, but no service is registered as that type.  You have `TestSvc1` registered as a `ITestSvc`, and only as that.  If you want to instead inject `TestSvc1`, you will need to add `AsSelf()` to its registration.

```
builder.RegisterType<TestSvc1>()
    .As<ITestSvc>()
    .AsSelf();
```

*Or* change your viewmodel so it accepts a `ITestSvc`.  This is probably the preferred solution.

Comment: Thank you for replying Amy! I changed it to an AsSelf(), and it is still cranky, but with the second error message. I tried putting in ITestSvc in the property and in the viewmodel constructor, but that yielded no difference. Any other thoughts? I feel like I'm missing something fundamental here, but this is my first time setting up Autofac in one of my projects. Thanks!
edit: Back to original error message, something didn't rebuild properly or didn't get to a bin folder

Comment: The same probably applies to the `TestViewModel` registration.  If you want to inject `Foo`, it needs to be registered as `Foo`.  If its registered as `IFoo`, you cannot ever inject it as a `Foo`.  Autofac doesn't know how to provide it.  Go through your registrations one by one and double check that your classes have dependencies on the registered services, not the concrete classes.

Comment: I'd like to add that I've never seen viewmodels injected like this.  I'm not sure if what you're trying to do is possible or bad practice...  Not saying its bad, I just have no idea.  Typically you inject services, not models.